# Children containers do not scale with their parent

Tags: html, css

I have 5 child divs in a parent div. The parent div does not fill the whole "window"-width", but all 5 children share the same space and fill their parent properly.

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child" style="background-color:red" >child 01</div>
  <div class="child" style="background-color:blue">child 02</div>
  <div class="child" style="background-color:yellow">child 
  03</div>
  <div class="child" style="background-color:grey">child 04</div>
  <div class="child" style="background-color:green">child05</div>
</div>
```

When I use `width: 90vw;` for the container of the parent div, the parent div scales, yet the child divs remain the same size. Shouldn't the child divs scale automatically with their parent? How do I get it to do that?

My CSS code:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css? 
family=Muli&display=swap');

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}

.parent {
  display: flex;
  width: 90vw;
}
```

Comment: Kindly update your question properly with [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and what you have tried so far

Comment: Hi Coding newbie, you would have to post your code, the question will be closed real soon if not. You can find more information on how to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your explanation, I think you need to give a value for a parent div width in Viewport Width(vw) and, you need to give the same width for their children div tags. For the demonstration purpose, I included five children div tags inside the parent tag and gave different colors to see their widths.

edit: I have done some changes to your CSS styles and I removed the import statement. I think it overrides our CSS styles.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
 font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}

.parent {
  display:"flex";
  width: 90vw;
}
.child{
    width:"100%";
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child" style="background-color:red" >child 01</div>
  <div class="child" style="background-color:blue">child 02</div>
  <div class="child" style="background-color:yellow">child 
  03</div>
  <div class="child" style="background-color:grey">child 04</div>
  <div class="child" style="background-color:green">child05</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I added your example but withouth the style attribute since I did this in css. My css I added also to the first post.

Comment: I updated my solution according to your requirement.

Comment: Thanks Wanuja, the trick with setting the child width's to 100% did the job. Since you have been so helpful you might be able to help me with a follow up problem I have run into. As you have noticed I want the container next to each other. I did this to create some kind of card system where you can extend one of them by clicking on it. Now, when the window is smaller, lets say less than 480px I want my CSS only display three of the five containers. So what I did is the following:

Comment: `code`@media(max-width: 480) {
    .parent {
    width: 100vw;
    }

    /* blend out the forth and fifth
    container */
    .child:nth-of-type(4), 
    .child:nth-of-type(5) {
        display: none;
    }
}`code`

Comment: unfortunately nothing changes if the window becomes smaller

Comment: I think you have written your media query in the wrong format. Use this method. @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) { .parent { width: 100vw; } 
 .child:nth-child(4) {
  display:none; } .child:nth-child(5) {
  display:none;
}}

Comment: I tried what you suggested, but still no changes.